# Pass InputBox String From HTML To Google Apps Script

Tags: html, input, box

I am trying to access the string the user enters in the HTML Service Input Box so I can use it in Apps Script.

The purpose of the message box is to test if the input box string was passed to the Apps Script.

I receive an undefined error. Would value any help...

```js
function showDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}

function MyMessage(userInput) {
    var MyMessage = Browser.msgBox(userInput)
}
```

```html
   
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
     </head>
     <body>
     <textarea id="user-input-box" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
     <input type="button" value="Submit" 
     onclick="google.script.run.MyMessage();" />
     <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close();" 
     />
     <script>
      function MyNote() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input-box").value;
      }
      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Which error do you receive? Paste it.

Comment: Thank You, Ikillnukes. When I type a string in the input box, and I click the submit button, the message box that appears says "undefined" rather than the string typed in the inputbox. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you attach also the `<script src=""`... Because the `google.script.run.MyMessage()` doesn't work.

Comment: Ikillnukes - would you mind showing me how that would look like, please?

Comment: I mean, your code is not complete, because, google.script.run doesn't exist for us.

Comment: I am sorry - I am not familiar with how to do that . . .

Comment: Can I share the link to the Google Sheet?

Comment: Yes, please, to make it work!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9TabZWn2dRCDKtay0eybd_xa6SLIJJeAYpogOGZolY/edit#gid=0